# Database or API to quickly check whether an image is a meme or not

Tags: data-request, api, images

Some websites like to illustrate articles with [meme](http://knowyourmeme.com/) pictures, which can be considered as funny or distracting, for instance depending whether you are at work or not. So I want to create a browser add-on to block them.

[image][image]

**QUESTION:** Is there a huge list of checksums/fingerprint of meme images, or an API to check whether an image is a meme or not?

Requirements:

- Identify memes even if resized
- Fast lookup time, less than a second
- Works even if the caption has been modified (memes are often the same image with a different caption, see second example above)

Comment: If you are aware of any Google Chrome extension that can block meme pictures: [Meme blocker for Google Chrome](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/28659/903)

Comment: Wouldn't figuring out if there is text written with all capitals using Impact with white text get you pretty close?

Comment: @svick: That would leave a large part of the pictures, for instance the first example above.

Comment: lazy option: blacklist most likely offending sites...4chan, imgur, etc. you'll lose a lot of non-meme content on each site, but that sounds much, much easier to implement. very interested to see programmatic solutions sprinkled with regex. or something i can't even comprehend.

Comment: @albert: Could you please move this comment to http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/28659/903 as it is a software tip rather than an answer to the present question? Thanks!

Comment: its a relevant comment that isn't mutually exclusive to software recommendations. added.

Comment: @albert : a list of the sites that these are most likely to come from would likely qualify as 'data' and be appropriate as an answer on here, too.

Comment: @Joe thanks, I wasn't 100% on that, appreciate the feedback